# How to retrieve the HTML content of a Google Sites footer with a Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classic-sites

I cannot find in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/site) an equivalent to `getSummary()` or `getTitle()` to retrieve the HTML content of a Google Sites [footer](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/191134?hl=en) (the custom footer editable through `Edit site layout > Custom Footer`).

`getHtmlContent()` only provides the content of the main div `#sites-canvas-main`.

```
var url = 'https://sites.google.com/a/test.net/';  
var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl(url);
var infos = {"title": site.getTitle(), "summary": site.getSummary()};
var page = site.getChildByName("home");
var content = page.getHtmlContent();
```

Comment: Do you mean the administrative footer with links like "report this site", or something else? I didn't see any editable footer field on the sites I played with... As a last resort, you can grab any element with [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) if the site is publicly accessible.

Comment: @MiceElf: The footer my question is referring to is the one editable through `Edit site layout > Custom Footer` as describe in this [documentation](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/191134?hl=en).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app):

```
function GetHtmlFooter() {
  var url = 'https://sites.google.com/a/test.net/'; 
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText("UTF-8");
  var footer = content.match('<div class="sites-subfooter-content"><div dir="ltr">(.*)</div></div></div>')[1];
  return footer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At this time there isn't a specific Google Apps Script method to retrieve the site custom footer of a Google Site through Google Apps Script nor through Google Sites API.

Submit a feature request to the Google Apps Script team. To do so,

1. Go to https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/
2. Click on "Send Feedback"
3. Click on "Apps Script Product feedback"
4. Fill up the Google Apps Script Sites feature request form and submit it.